# How to have a class return a string that isn't defined in __init__

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a class that samples from a probability distribution and returns a string based on that sampling. Currently, instead of returning a string as I'd like, I'm getting an object. I know python classes require a string method to print correctly, but I'm not sure how to return the particular string that is sampled every time the method is called.

```
class ProbabilityDistribution(object):
  def __init__(self, countMap):
    self.countMap = countMap
    self.total = float(sum(self.countMap.values()))
    self.probMap =  { k: (v / self.total) for k, v in self.countMap.items() }

  def __str__(self):
    ????

  def sample(self):
    sampleVal = random(0,1)
    count = 0.0
    for x in self.countMap.keys():
      count = count + self.probMap[x]
      if count > sampleVal:
        return x
```

Comment: what are you trying to print?

Comment: after returning x in the sample method I'd like to be able to print it

Answer (score 2):

`__str__` is supposed to be a representation of the object that will be useful when you type `print my_obj` in the interactive terminal.

If your object represents a probability distribution, it should probably print something like:

```
<ProbabilityDistribution, 3 bins>
```

or

```
ProbabilityDistribution([0.1, 0.3, 0.6])
```

and not

```
2
```

In my opinion, the act of sampling an element from the probability distribution should not be mixed together with the act of printing the value.

If you need to sample numbers from the distribution and print them, do something like:

```
for n in range(n_samples):
    x = distribution.sample()
    print x
```

Comment: the OP just wants to see the value of `x` which is returned in the method and countMap is obviously a dict not a list

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, I don't want to print directly from the class, I want to be able to call sample and then use the result as a regular string.

Comment: Looks like `sample()` returns a key from `probMap`, and you copy `probMap`'s keys from `countMap`, so you need to look at whatever type  you're using for keys in `countMap`.

Comment: countMap and probMap are both {String:Float}

Answer (score 0):

You could have `sample()` store the value in a private field before returning it. If you simply call `sample()` every time you want to turn the object into a string, you'll get a different string every time. This way you'll only get a new string when you call `sample()`. Add this to the `__init__` method:

```
self.mostRecentSample = None
```

And change this in the `sample` method:

```
if count > sampleVal:
    self.mostRecentSample = x
    return x
```

And then your `__str__` method is this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(mostRecentSample)
```

### EDIT

As noted by others, it should be said that this is a rather awkward use of `__str__` and isn't what the method is intended for. If possible I would recommend seeing how else you can go about designing your implementation .